# Linked List using templates and smart pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, generics, pointers

I have an implementation of `Linked List` with `push`, `pop`, `size`, `print` and `search` functionalities. This is also an attempt to learn smart pointers. I have only used `shared_pointers` in this implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

// Class for individual nodes in the list
template<typename T>
class Node
{
    T val;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> next = nullptr;
public:
    Node(T value)
    {
        val = value;
    }
    T get_val() const;
    void set_next(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>);
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> get_next() const;
};

template<typename T>
T Node<T>::get_val() const
{
    return val;
}

template<typename T>
void Node<T>::set_next(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> node)
{
    next = node;
}

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> Node<T>::get_next() const
{
    return next;
}

// Class for the Linked List
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    /*std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> head = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(nullptr);
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> tail = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(nullptr);*/

    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> tail;
    std::size_t size_var = 0;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
    }
    void push(T);
    T pop();
    int search(T) const;
    void print() const;
    std::size_t size() const;
};

// Insert node at head
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::push(T value)
{
    auto new_node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);
    // Check if the list already has values and push values at the head accordingly
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        auto temp = head;
        head = new_node;
        new_node -> set_next(temp);
    }
    size_var++;
}

// Remove node at tail
template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::pop()
{
    T value = tail -> get_val();
    auto node = head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> prev;
    // Set the tail to second last value and set its next to nullptr.
    while(node)
    {
        if(node -> get_next() == nullptr)
        {
            //std::cout << "Tail count first: " << node.use_count() << "\n";
            tail = prev;
            //std::cout << "Tail count second: " << node.use_count() << "\n";
            tail -> set_next(nullptr);
            //std::cout << "Tail count third: " << node.use_count() << "\n";
            break;
        }
        prev = node;
        node = node -> get_next();
    }
    size_var--;
    return value;
}

//Returns the index of the value if found, else returns zero.
template<typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::search(T value) const
{
    auto node = head;
    int index = 0;
    while(node)
    {
        if(node -> get_val() == value)
        {
            return index;
        }
        node = node -> get_next();
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}

// Print the list
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::print() const
{
    auto node = head;
    std::cout << "Printing List: \n";
    while(node)
    {
        std::cout << node -> get_val() << "\t";
        node = node -> get_next();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Return the size of the list
template<typename T>
std::size_t LinkedList<T>::size() const
{
    return size_var;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> ll{};
    for(int i = 8; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ll.push(i);
    }
    ll.print();
    std::cout << "Size: " << ll.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Pop: " << ll.pop() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size: " << ll.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Pop: " << ll.pop() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size: " << ll.size() << "\n";
    ll.push(9);
    ll.print();
    std::cout << "Size: " << ll.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Search: " << ll.search(10) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Search: " << ll.search(5) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The `push` inserts a new node or item at the head of the list while `pop` removes an item from the tail. The `search` returns an index or position of the item if value being searched for is found.

1. Is the usage of smart pointers correct? Are there any leaks, especially in `pop`?
2. Are there any place in this code where I should be using `std::unique_ptr`? I felt that there is always a possibility of more than one pointer being pointed to any node; hence I avoided `std::unique_ptr`.
3. What should be the return type of `search`, `bool` or `int` or `std::size_t`? If it is `std::size_t`, is `std::optional` the best way to indicate search failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I'd recommend avoiding returning the value from `pop`. If `T`'s copy constructor throws, you lose the data. So I would introduce `T top() const` and use it along with non-returning `void pop()`. This approach is used in `STL` containers which have a `pop` method. Also calling `pop` on empty list leads to UB.
2. In my opinion, a linked list based on `std::unique_ptr` looks more natural. But if you switch to that you will lose some functionality used in your approach based on `std::shared_ptr`, like `head` and `tail` point to one node, and the lack of copy-constructor and assignment operator.
3. Having a `search` method is nice, but more generic would be having compatibility with *forward iterator*s that makes it possible to use STL algorithms with your container.
4. You didn't define copy-constructor and assignment operator. Is that done intentionally because shared pointers were used? Try to make test returning local copy of a `LinkedList` object from the function; I wonder what the result would be. From my point of view, it would be nice to have more STL-like behavior for the container.

Comment: Thank you for the review. I didn't consider copy constructor and assignment operator because I was more focused on using smart pointers correctly and providing required functionality.